# Handling TableAdapter Null Values

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a query in a TableAdapter that wrapped this SQL (Oracle SQL, uses ':' instead of '@' for parameterized variable), which I called `GetModel()`

```
SELECT MFG_PRODUCT FROM FRAME_NO
WHERE FRM_NO = :FRM_NO
```

I expected the query might return null values, so I set the column `MFG_PRODUCT` null value to be `Null` as pointed by this guideline from Microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya91ataz(v=vs.100).aspx

However, my application still throw exception when the query returned no rows. What should I do?

I have rebuild the whole solution just in case that the code still referencing the old compiled dataset, but still, no luck.

Edited: Here is the code. The exception is thrown when the returned value is null

```
try
{
    String modelCode = frameAdapter.GetModelCode(txtStdFrameId.Text.Trim()).ToString();
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelCode)) //Go directly to exception when data is null here
    {
       //Process the data 
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     //Log error to a text file
}
```

Comment: What exceptions are being thrown? What details are included in the exceptions?

Comment: how do you handle the returned rows? does this happen only when data has no row

Comment: Yes, it happens only when returned data has no rows. The exception is `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: that line `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelCode))` cannot throw exception.

Comment: put a break point in your code to know where exactly the exception is thrown - it's probably your `frameAdapter.GetModelCode()`

Comment: Yes, the exception is thrown at the `frameAdapter.GetModelCode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a column to `NULL` this way does not have anything to do with your empty data rows. It will only work if you have at least one row and columns in that row are `NULL`

For data returning no rows, you will have to handle this case yourself

```
//DataTable
DataTable dt = ds.Fill(..);

//handle no rows 
if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
   //what do you want to do here
}
else
{
   //this dt contains at least one row, now I can use it without any errors/exception
}
```

Comment: The query is setup as single value returned function in dataset, so it does not return a datatable object, because the parameter is a primary key.

Comment: You still need to check if there is at least one row. When your db does not return anything, there is nothing to access and you get a Null exception. This is from `.Net`. If the NULL is from your DB you'll get the value as DBNull.Value which won't throw exception in C#

Comment: if that explanation was not enough then you need to post your code

Comment: How can I check the number of returned rows when the tableadapter returned value is String?

Comment: use `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returned_value))`. Why didn't you post your code. That would make it easier to help

Comment: I have edited the question, plus the code. The way you suggested above didn't work, still get into the exception.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. It is because of the typo error in this line:
`String modelCode = frameAdapter.GetModelCode(txtStdFrameId.Text.Trim()).ToString();`

Apparently converting a `null` to String that triggered the error. 
It should be like this:
`String modelCode = frameAdapter.GetModelCode(txtStdFrameId.Text.Trim());`